# WinError 10054 whenever I close my PyGame system

Tags: python, pygame, pyscripter

Every time I close my system (made in Python using PyGame module) I receive the this:

EOFError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This is what is output by the system:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 73, in
>   execInThread   File "", line 44, in **call**   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py",
>   line 196, in **call**   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in
>   syncreq   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 431, in
>   sync_request   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 379, in
>   serve   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 337, in
>   _recv   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 50, in recv 
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 166, in read
>   EOFError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host

I have no idea what is causing this and any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 and have got the error on each different PC i try

Comment: Could you provide an MCVE in your post so we can all reproduce the problem..

Comment: I am finding it really difficult to reproduce this error so is it possible for me to upload all of the required files for the current version in its entirety?

Comment: It depends how long it is.  More than 10-20 lines you should not but that or under that you should, just so that the problem is reproducible.  Shorten it as much as possible.

Comment: Does this error occur when you execute your code outside of PyScripter?